# AWS API Gateway auth with Chrome extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension, oauth, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

is there any possibility how to use Chrome(Google) identity to authenticate AWS API Gateway?

I know that AWS Cognito supports Google as external federated identity provider. However when creating OAuth client within Google Developers console for my Chrome App, only ClientID is generated. App secret is is available for web apps, mobile..., but not Chrome App.

Thank you for any advice.
Regards,
Robert

Comment: In other words, you want to login using Google to get the temporary credentials for web service?